# Applications of finite speed of propagation property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, wave-equation

Consider the Laplace operator $\Delta:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\partial_{x_{j}}^{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $E_{\lambda}$ be the spectral resolution of $\Delta$, and
$$ H_{t}[f]:=\cos{(t\sqrt{-\Delta})}f=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos{t\sqrt{\lambda}}dE_{\lambda}f\qquad \forall f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
be the Huygens operator.

For any $u_{0}\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the function
$$ u(x,t)=(H_{t}[u_{0}])(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t\sqrt{\lambda})dE_{\lambda}u_{0}$$
solves
\begin{equation}\label{1-7}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}-\Delta u=0   , & \hbox{on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,+\infty)$;} \\
u_{t}(x,0)=0, & \hbox{$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$;} \\
    u(x,0)=u_{0}, & \hbox{$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.}
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
The Huygens operator $H_t$ admits a kernel given by
\begin{equation}
  w(x,y,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t\sqrt{\lambda})de(x,y,\lambda) 
\end{equation}
Here, $e(x,y,\lambda)$ is the spectral function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It follows that, for any fixed $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $w(x,y,t)$ satisfies the equation

\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
 (\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}-\Delta_{x})w(x,y,t) =0   , & \hbox{on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,+\infty)$;} \\
w_{t}(x,y,0)=0, & \hbox{$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$;} \\
    w(x,y,0)=\delta_{y}(x), & \hbox{$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.}
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $\Delta_{\Omega}$ be the Dirichlet Laplacian operator on $\Omega$, and $E_{\lambda,\Omega}$ the corresponding spectral resolution. We can also defined the Huygens operator
$$ H_{t}^{\Omega}[f]:=\cos{(t\sqrt{-\Delta_{\Omega}})}f=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos{t\sqrt{\lambda}}dE_{\lambda,\Omega}f\qquad \forall f\in L^2(\Omega)$$
We denote by $w_{\Omega}(x,y,t)$ the kernel of $H_{t}^{\Omega}$:
$$   w_{\Omega}(x,y,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t\sqrt{\lambda})de_{\Omega}(x,y,\lambda), $$
where $e_{\Omega}(x,y,\lambda)$ is the spectral function of $-\Delta_{\Omega}$. Similarly, for fixed $y\in \Omega$, $w_{\Omega}(x,y,t)$ satisfies the equations:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
 (\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}-\Delta_{x})w_{\Omega}(x,y,t) =0   , & \hbox{on $\Omega \times (0,+\infty)$;} \\
w_{\Omega}(x,y,t)=0, & \hbox{$\forall x\in \partial\Omega$;} \\
(w_{\Omega})_{t}(x,y,0)=0, & \hbox{$\forall x\in \Omega$;} \\
    w_{\Omega}(x,y,0)=\delta_{y}(x), & \hbox{$\forall x\in \Omega$.}
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

In (1.6) of the paper *Seeley, R.*, [**A sharp asymptotic remainder estimate for the eigenvalues of the Laplacian in a domain of (R^3)**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90013-0), Adv. Math. 29, 244-269 (1978). [ZBL0382.35043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0382.35043). , it claims the following fact that
$$ w(x,y,t)=w_{\Omega}(x,y,t) \tag{*}$$
holds for all $|t|\leq d(y,\partial\Omega)$ and all $x\in \Omega$.

**My Question:** *How can we prove the conclusion $(*)$ by means of the finite speed of propagation property of wave equation?*

**Remark:** I review many other papers, but all of them just write "this is due to the "Finite Speed of Propagation Property". I feel very confuse about the details in applying the finite speed of propagation property. Can someone help me with above question? Thank you very much!

Recall that the **Finite Speed of Propagation Property** states that:

> Let $u(x,t)$ solves $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}-\Delta u=0$. If $u(x,t)=u_{t}(x,t)=0$ on the set $B(x_0,t_0)\times\{t=0\}$, then $u(x,t)=0$ on $K(x_0,t_0):=\{(x,t)|0\leq t\leq t_0, |x-x_0|\leq t_0-t\}$.

Comment: Apply the finite speed of propagation property to $u = w - w_\Omega$ (where $w_\Omega$ is extended arbitrarily to the entire Euclidean space), and note that $\Omega$ contains $B(y,t)$ whenever $y \in \Omega$ and $t \leq d(y,\partial \Omega)$.  (If one is worried about the discontinuities of the extension of $w_\Omega$, one can convolve $u$ by some mollifier (approximation to the identity) if desired, though with the theory of distributions this is not really necessary.)

Comment: (Strictly speaking, one needs a version of the finite speed of propagation property that also allows for an inhomogeneous term, but this can be deduced from the version you stated via Duhamel's formula.)

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you for your comments! But I am still confuse about the restriction $t\leq d(y,\partial\Omega)$. Here is my understanding: After extended $w_{\Omega}$ to the entire Euclidean space, for any fixed $y\in \Omega$, $u=w-w_{\Omega}$ satisfies $\partial_{t}^{2}u-\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,+\infty)$, and for any $x_0\in \Omega$, we can find $B(x_0,r_0)$ ($r_0$ large enough) such that $\Omega\times [0,d(y,\partial\Omega)] \subset K(x_0,r_0)$. Then applying the finite speed of propagation property to $u$ in the set $B(x_0,r_0)\times\{t=0\}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @TerryTao However, according to the arguments above, it seems that we can choose $r_0$ as large as possible, such that $\Omega\times [0, m\cdot d(y,\partial\Omega)]\subset K(x_0,r_0)$ as $m\to+\infty$. This seems very strange to me.

Comment: $w - w_\Omega$ only solves the wave equation in the interior and exterior of $\Omega$; on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ there will be a distributional forcing term.

Comment: okay, I see. Are there exists some reference that provided the strict proof of conclusion (*)?